# How can I increase the body of snake when it eats the food

Tags: c

I'm creating a snake game using C language.
Here I created four functions

`draw`  -> Print the snake and border

`input` -> Reads user input

`logic` -> perform operation based on user input

`setup` -> Keep track of score and gameover

```
//GLOBAL VARIABLES
bool gameover = false;
const int width = 20, height = 20;
int x, y, fruitX, fruitY, score, flag;


//SETUP() DEFINATION
void setUp()
{
    gameover = false;
    x = width / 2;
    y = height / 2;
    label1:
    fruitX = (int)rand() % width-1;
    if(fruitX <= 0 || fruitX >= height || fruitX >= width)
        goto label1;

    label2:
    fruitY = (int)rand() % height-1;
    if(fruitY <= 0 || fruitY >= height || fruitY >= width)
        goto label2;
    score = 0;
}


//DRAW() DEFINATION
void draw()
{
    system("clear");

    // TOP AREA
    for(int i = 0; i < width+2; i++)
    {
        printf("#");
    }
    printf("\n");

    // MIDDLE AREA
    for(int i = 0; i < width; i++)
    {
        for(int j = 0; j < height; j++)
        {
            if(j == 0)
            {
                printf("#");
            }
            if(x == i && y == j)
            {
                printf("0");
            }
            else if(fruitX == i && fruitY == j)
            {
                printf("f");
            }
            else if(j == width-1)
            {
                printf("#");
            }
            else
            {
                printf(" ");
            } 
        }
        printf("\n");
    }

    // BOTTOM AREA
    for(int i = 0; i < width+2; i++)
    {
        printf("#");
    }
    printf("\n");
    printf("Score : %d",score);
}


//VOID() DEFINATION
void input()
{
    if(kbhit())
    {
        switch(_getch())
        {
            case 'w' :
                flag = 1;
                break;
            case 'z' :
                flag = 2;
                break;
            case 'a' :
                flag = 3;
                break;
            case 's' :
                flag = 4;
                break;
            case 27 :
                exit(0);

        }
    }
}



//LOGIC() DEFINATION
void logic()
{
    switch(flag)
    {
        case 1: // UP
            x--;
            usleep(200000);
            break;
        case 2: //DOWN
            x++;
            usleep(200000);
            break;
        case 3:  //LEFT
            y--;
            usleep(200000);
            break;
        case 4:  //RIGHT
            y++;
            usleep(200000);
            break;
    }
    if(x == width || y == height || x == -1 || y == -1)
    {
        gameover = 1;
    }
    if(x == fruitX && y == fruitY)
    {
        label1:
        fruitX = (int)rand() % width-1;
        if(fruitX <= 0 || fruitX >= width || fruitX >= height)
            goto label1;
        label2:
        fruitY = (int)rand() % height-1;
        if(fruitY <= 0 || fruitY >= width || fruitY >= height)
            goto label2;
        score += 5;
    }
}


int main()
{
    setUp();
    while(!gameover)
    {
        draw();
        input();
        logic();
    }
    return 0;
}
```

I want to increase the length of the snake body by one unit every time when snake eats the food.

I don't know what algorithm should I apply to increase the length of the body.

Comment: You're going to need some kind of data structure (array, linked list, etc.) to contain all the segments of your snake.

Comment: Avoid `goto`. Restructure your program so that you don't have to use `goto`...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I don't know what algorithm should I apply to increase the length of the body.

It can be done in many ways but modelling the snake using a single coordinate `(x, y)` is for sure not going to do. You need "something" extra to know all about the snakes position.

One simple approach is a doubly linked list of coordinates. Something like:

```
struct snake
{
    unsigned int x;
    unsigned int y;
    struct snake *next;
    struct snake *prev;
}
```

And then have code like:

```
// Create snake
struct snake *head;    // head of snake
struct snake *tail;    // tail of snake

head = malloc(*head);  // Add first node
assert(head != NULL);
head->x = start_position_x;
head->y = start_position_y;
head-next = NULL;
head-prev = NULL;
tail = head;
```

Now the list contains 1 node which means the snake is 1 long.

When you want to increase the length, you add a new node to the list so that it contains two nodes (i.e. snake is 2 long) and so on.

When you move the snake, take the tail-node, update its coordinates and move it to the front.

When drawing the snake, you need to check every node in the list.

Another simple approach could be a big (!!) array of coordinates that is used as a circular buffer. Something like:

```
#define MAX_SNAKE_LEN 4096
struct snake snake_arr[MAX_SNAKE_LEN];
unsigned int head_index = 0;
unsigned int tail_index = 0;
snake_arr[head_index].x = start_position_x;
snake_arr[head_index].y = start_position_y;
```

When moving the snake simply put the new "head" at position `head_index + 1` and increment head and tail index. When head or tail index reach MAX_SNAKE_LEN set them back to zero (i.e. a circular buffer), e.g. by using code like `tail_index = (tail_index + 1) % MAX_SNAKE_LEN;`.

When increasing snake length simply increment head index without incrementing tail.

When drawing the snake, you must use all array element between (and including) `head_index` and `tail_index`.

These two algorithms are probably not the most efficient ways to model the snake but both are rather simple to implement.

BTW:

`goto` should be avoided.

Use of global variables should in general also be avoided.

Comment: I don't understand why you said not to use " goto " does it have any disadvantage ?

Comment: @NagrocksNaa Not really disadvantage in terms of execution. It's more that code with `goto` is quickly evolves into spaghetti-code being hard to understand, debug and maintain. Use loops like `for` and `while` instead.